# How do I add a new class to an element dynamically?

Tags: css, addclass

Is there any way to add a new CSS class to an element on `:hover`?

Like for jQuery, but translated into CSS:

```
$(element).addClass('someclass');
```

Comment: Not with just CSS. jQuery or js is the only way to actually change the class of an element dynamically.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Short answer no :)

But you could just use the same CSS for the hover like so:

```
a:hover, .hoverclass {
    background:red;
}
```

Maybe if you explain why you need the class added, there may be a better solution?

Comment: "You could just" in your contrived simple example; there are situations when it would be useful, when "you could just" doesn't apply.

Answer (score 24):

Since everyone has given you jQuery/JS answers to this, I will provide an additional solution. The answer to your question is still no, but using LESS (a CSS Pre-processor) you can do this easily.

```
.first-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.second-class:hover {
  .first-class;
}
```

Quite simply, any time you hover over `.second-class` it will give it all the properties of `.first-class`. Note that it won't add the class permanently, just on hover. You can learn more about LESS here: [Getting Started with LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Here is a SASS way to do it as well:

```
.first-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.second-class {
  &:hover {
    @extend .first-class;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

CSS really doesn't have the ability to modify an object in the same manner as JavaScript, so in short - no.

Answer (score 3):

`:hover` is a pseudoclass, so you can put your CSS declarations there:

```
a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}
```

You can also use a list of selectors to apply CSS declarations to a hovered element or an element with a certain class:

```
.some-class,
a:hover {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why @Marco Berrocl get a negative feedback and his answer is totally right 
what about using a library to make some animation so i need to call the class in hover to element not copy the code from the library and this will make me slow.

so i think hover not the answer and he should use jquery or javascript in many cases

Comment: The second sentence of Marco's answer is factually incorrect - there is a difference between "need to use" and "can use". Also, please consider using punctuation to improve the readability of your answers, especially for non-native speakers like myself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - first capture the event using `onmouseover`, then set the class name using
[`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

If you like to add or remove classes - use the more convenient [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
method.

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover=className="active">
  Hover this!
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked for a CSS solution ... onmouseover=className="active" <-- this is JS

Comment: Good job answering the question's title!

Answer (score -2):

Using CSS only, no. You need to use jQuery to add it.

Comment: You only need javascript to do it